# Merge Google Reminders Calendar with Primary Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

On the Google Calendar, I went ahead and switched from Tasks to Reminders. Perfect, I now see a new calendar called "Reminders" that shows them all.

However, I have a Todoist integration that syncs up with my Google Calendar, but since the Reminders calendar is a separate calendar, they don't show up in Todoist. It doesn't appear that the Reminders calendar can even be shared.

Is there a way to ensure Google Reminders get added to the primary calendar? Or is there an automated way to copy them over to the primary calendar when a new one is added?

Answer (score 4):

This may not be possible, because the "Reminders" feature in Google Calendar isn't actually a calendar (even though it appears in the calendar list). It belongs to its own separate "Reminders" part of your Google Profile, which [does not have an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728176/is-there-a-public-google-api-to-access-reminders-set-in-google-now-or-google-kee).

*Some Background:* Google originally created the Reminders feature for the Google Now mobile app, back in 2013. It was incorporated into the Google Calendar app in [2015](https://blog.google/products/calendar/add-to-dos-to-your-google-calendar/) with the ability to set and view reminders, but the data itself stayed external to Google Calendar. It expanded to the desktop version in [2016](https://blog.google/products/calendar/reminders-come-to-google-calendar-on-the-web/), and today, it integrates with a variety of Google Apps, including Google Keep and [Inbox](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6062813?hl=en).